# What is the geometric meaning of differentials of higher order than the first?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, differential

As the title suggests, I was wondering what could be the geometric meaning of differentials of higher order than the first, being aware that the first order differential is a linear application that approximates linearly the increment of the function itself at a point.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same idea, [jets of functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_(mathematics))

Comment: In physics terms you have velocity, acceleration, [jerk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerk_(physics)) etc. In a rollercoaster ride acceleration is the force you feel, and jerk is how that changes and is what throws you around and determines how rough a ride it is.

Answer (score 0):

The second derivative of a function corresponds to the curvature or concavity of the graph. The graph of a function with a positive second derivative is upwardly concave, while the graph of a function with a negative second derivative curves in the opposite way.

Similarly, the third derivative of a function corresponds to the change of the curvature of the graph.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but my doubt was about the differentials, not about the derivatives